# Upgrade Rails 3 to 5, scope block syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deprecated, rails-upgrade

I'm upgrading an app from Rails 3.2 to 5.2, I need to have both versions running at the same time and have run into an issue with the scope block syntax.

I've got this relationship on a Project model

```
has_many   :companies_projects, include: :company_type, order: 'company_types.order_id'
```

which gives this error in Rails 5

```
Unknown key: :include. Valid keys are: :class_name, :anonymous_class, :foreign_key etc...
```

i can fix this by changing the syntax to this:

```
has_many   :companies_projects, ->{ includes( :company_type ).order('company_types.order_id') }
```

but then in the rails 3 app it causes this error:

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

is there a happy medium where this scope block will work in both rails 3 and 5? any help would be appriciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question!

You can solve this puzzle by replacing your relation with this conditional expression:

```
if Gem::Requirement.new('>= 4.0.0').satisfied_by?(Gem.loaded_specs['activerecord'].version)
  has_many :companies_projects, ->{ includes(:company_type).order('company_types.order_id') }
else
  has_many :companies_projects, include: :company_type, order: 'company_types.order_id'
end
```

It checks which version of the `activerecord` gem is loaded, and creates relationship using suitable syntax.

(I might be wrong but as I remember new syntax of `has_many` was introduced in the version `4.0.0`.)

Comment: thanks for the response!
hmm yeah I was worried this might be the solution. Really don't want to clutter up all the models with these conditions everywhere.  Is there a way to write a single scope on a relationship that is valid in Rails 3 and Rails 5?

Comment: Well, simple cases such as ```has_many :companies_projects, class_name: 'CompaniesProject'``` can be left unchanged. What about ```arel```-related query modifiers, in Rails >= 4 they are accepted only as a callable ```scope```, not as a ```options``` hash of ```has_many```. I was trying to solve this dilemma a year ago too but eventually stayed with the solution above.

Comment: ah well hopefully this upgrade won't take _too_ long... thanks for the help